# How to index a Julia array

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

I am having trouble understanding what seems like an inconsistent behavior in Julia.

```
X = reshape(1:100, 10, 10)
b = [1 5 9]
X[2, :][b] # returns the correct array
X[2, :][1 5 9] # throws an error
```

Can someone explain why using the variable `b` works to index an array but not when I write the index myself?

Answer (score 10):

Since `x = X[2,:]` is just a vector, we can simplify the example to just talking about indexing behavior on vectors.

`x[v]` where `v` is a collection of integers returns the subset of `x`. Thus `x[(1,5,9)]`, or `x[[1,5,9]]` is thus using that `getindex(x::Vector,i::AbstractArray)` dispatch.

Note that `x[[1 5 9]]` works because `v = [1 5 9]` makes `v` a row vector. That's valid syntax, but `x[1 5 9]` just isn't even valid Julia syntax. That syntax means something else:

```
v = Float64[1 5 9]
```

returns a row vector with element type `Float64`.

Comment: Interesting - it seems to be valid syntax because you could do: `X = Float64; X[1 5 9]`. And error is not from parsing but just about typed_hcat(T, ...) missing. But I am not able to define appropriate typed_hcat function! Why?

Comment: that's because `typed_hcat` is for what I showed up there: the first argument should be a data type that is the element-type for the resulting array. I believe this is built into the core Julia since it's special parsing and handling for array construction.

Comment: @Liso: try `Base.typed_hcat(::AbstractArray, ::Int...) = "Don't do this!"`.

Comment: What I find interesting is that `(1:10)[[1 4]]` and `(1:10)[[1, 4]].'` result in different types. I wonder if there's a valid reason for this, or just a historical remnant of how the two were developed so far.

Comment: You lost dimension with `(1:10)[[1, 4]]`. Try this `(1:10)[[1, 4],:]` or this `(1:10)[[1, 4],:].'` (or `reshape((1:10)[[1, 4]], (2,1))` )

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out a solution.

Rather than write `X[2, :][1 5 9]` I should have written `x[2, :][[1 5 9]]`

I believe this makes sense when we imagine indexing on two dimensions the second time. This makes it possible to write more complicate indices, like `X[2:4, :][[1 3],[1 3]]`

Comment: As long as you understand that `X[2:4, :][[1 3],[1 3]]` returns 4 elements rather than 2 (which might be what you expect if you're coming from python).